# Angular2 for mobile development

Tags: angular

If I use Angular2 for mobile development, could I still get access to device features like camera, GPS(location) and local device storage? For which functionalities, I'll need to know native ios/android programming?

Comment: you should be looking at mobile based frameworks..maybe nativescript or ionic 2.. this can be easily googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to combine Angular with Ionic or Angular with Nativescript. 
After deciding which combination you prefer check their documentation.